# UITouch blocked after using MPMoviePlayerController's view

Tags: ios, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller, uitouch

I have a `UIButton` at the top left of the screen. Using iOS simulator, I can easily touch the farthest most top left part of the button. It works as expected:

[image]

But after using `MPMoviePlayerController`, the button doesn't work when pressed in that region! (can be a bit bigger/smaller). Sounds crazy!

`MPMoviePlayerController` Code:

```
if (!_player) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];        

    NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryErr];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationErr];

    VCRoot* root = [[ApplicationManager sharedManager] rootViewController];

    _player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    _player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    _player.view.hidden = YES;
    [root.view addSubview:_player.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerStateChanged:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];
} else {
    [_player stop];
}

_player.contentURL = [channel url];

[_player setInitialPlaybackTime:-1.0];
[_player play];
```

NOTE:

I tried adding the `_player.view` using `insertSubview: AtIndex:0`, tried `setIsUserInteractionEnabled = NO`, tried `setAlpha = 0.f`, all no use .. I even added it as a subview of a different view.

HOWEVER:

When I stop the player, and remove the view, that area is touchable again :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of all the things I tried ... Finally:

`_player.view.frame = CGRectMake(-100, -100, 1.f, 1.f);`

worked!